# How to make truffle oil?

Tags: truffles, olive-oil

Is it as easy as taking a few shavings of truffle, and chucking them into glass bottle filled with olive oil, and then sealing it up and waiting a few months?

I'd rather not mess this up, as they are pretty pricey!

Comment: If you have fresh truffles why waste them on oil?

Comment: Well, as truffles are pretty pricey and hard to come by.  From one truffle you can make a load of bottles, and give them to your mates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it is that easy.  But it is a costly endeaver.  I have know chefs to make it with a pure olive oil or grape seed oil.  Some heat it to 220 degrees or so but I have meet some that don't.  The ones that didn't made sure to pull the oxygen from the bottle with one of those wine vacuum savers.

I have been told self made truffle oil will lose it truffle flavor due to most the flavor actually coming from an odorant.  I have not personally made any so I can't speak from experience on how long it will hold.

All the above being said. If I had the money to buy some truffle, I am not sure the best use for them would be to make truffle oil.